# Is there an alternative to gobject.timeout_add() in Python?

Tags: python, gobject

I'm using gobject.timeout_add() to display a timer in my project ([dojotools](http://github.com/flavioamieiro/dojotools)).

I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve the same results, but without the gobject dependency.

The requirement is just calling a method repeatedly, in a certain time interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a thread with time.sleep(interval) to achieve the same effect.

```
import thread, time

def timer():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        # do something here

thread.start_new_thread(timer, ())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using TkInter, which should be available on all Pythons (except cell phones and maybe some tablets), you can use TkInter's `after()` function.
That would avoid the blocking that sleep causes.